google-autenticator openvpn not working pam?
Hy All.
I have been struggling with google-authenticator + pam..
Ubuntu 24.04
openvpn2.6.9-1ubuntu4 amd64.
server.conf
....
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn login USERNAME password 
PASSWORD pin OTP"
#plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn login USERNAME password 
PASSWORD"
#plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
.....

I have tried all plugin versions above...
client.vpn
...
auth-nocache
static-challenge "Google Authenticator Token" 1
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/pauloric.contatoglobal.com.br/openvpn.secret
...

/etc/pam.d/openvpn
#auth   [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_google_authenticator.so nullok user=root secret=/etc/goggle/${USER} no_strict_owner forward_pass debug authtok_prompt=pin 
echo_verification_code

auth    required        pam_google_authenticator.so nullok user=root secret=/etc/goggle/${USER} no_strict_owner forward_pass authtok_prompt=pin echo_verification_code debug
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so 

error message:
2024-05-06T19:54:24.270755-03:00 cerberus openvpn(pam_google_authenticator)[7291]: debug: start of google_authenticator for "pauloric"
**2024-05-06T19:54:24.270882-03:00 cerberus openvpn(pam_google_authenticator)[7291]: debug: end of google_authenticator for "pauloric". Result: The return value should be ignored by PAM dispatch**
2024-05-06T19:54:24.275435-03:00 cerberus openvpn[7291]: pam_unix(openvpn:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=192.168.11.11  user=pauloric
2024-05-06T19:54:24.334720-03:00 cerberus openvpn[7291]: pam_sss(openvpn:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=192.168.11.11 user=pauloric
2024-05-06 19:54:24 192.168.11.11:36176 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=0
2024-05-06 19:54:24 192.168.11.11:36176 TLS: Username/Password authentication succeeded for username 'pauloric' 

As I can see without google all goes up and running.
Inserting google authenticator - If I put code or not It gives me this message and the user connects...
What am I missing?

Can you try this
# enable multi-factor authentication with google authenticator
reneg-sec 0
plugin openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn login USERNAME password PASSWORD 'verification code' OTP"
verify-client-cert none
username-as-common-name

I got it from the OpenVPN forums
https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=34017

thanks Guido, but it didn´t solve. I already used reneg-sec 0 in cient.conf.
verify-client-cert none insert an error  ( claiming wrong /etc/openvpn/ccd....) and username-as-common-name did not solved to.
Problem is problably with pam + google-autenticator and no message is agregated with plugin openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn login USERNAME password PASSWORD 'verification code' OTP"...  I am trying with all alternatives that i have been looking for .. but none solve my problem...

man, nobody deserve this kind of error... it was a typo at secret=/etc/goggle/${USER} . It still  is no working, but message is different now... Iĺl debug more to see If I can solve . Thanks for all that see this message and tried to solve.   Consider this closed....
